# Determining the quotient of a $2n$ degree and a linear polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

> Find the quotient of polynomials $f(x)=x^{2n}-nx^{n+1}+nx^{n-1}-1$ and $g(x)=x-1$.

I know that by the remainder theorem the remainder is $f(1)=1-n+n-1=0$ so we can write $f(x)=(x-1)q(x)$ but beyond that I don't know what to do even though I tried doing the division, as well as guessing the quotient to find its coefficients using the polynomial equality theorem, but these approaches got me nowhere.

Comment: You might consider factoring $x^{2n}-1$ and $-nx^{n-1}(x^2-1)$ separately then adding the results together...

Comment: Write $f(x)$ as $x^{2n}-1-nx^{n-1}(x^{2}-1)$ and use the identity $a^m-b^m=(a-b)(a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}b+...+ab^{m-2}+b^{m-1})$ with $a=x$, $b=1$ and $m=2n$ and with $m=2$.

Comment: Did it, got $(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+1)(x^n+1)-nx^{n-1}(x+1)$.

Comment: @user562834 You will get $(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+1)(x+1)-nx^{n-1}(x+1)(x-1)$ and when you divide by $x+1$ you will get $(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+1)-nx^{n-1}(x-1)$